# How should I unit test mapDispatchToProps in Redux?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux

How should write a unit test to ensure that mapDispatchToProps correctly returns action creators that are wrapped in the dispatch function?

I am currently using Mocha and Enzyme for testing.

Here is my container component.

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Sidebar from '/components/Sidebar'
import Map from '/components/Map'
import * as LayerActions from '../actions/index'

// Use named export for unconnected component (for tests)
export const App = ({layers, actions} ) => (
    <div>
     <Sidebar LayerActions={actions} />
     <Map /> 
    </div>
)

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  layers: state.layers
})

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(LayerActions, dispatch)
})

// Use default export for the connected component (for app)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would actually suggest that you *not* try to do that.  Unless you have a very specific need to make use of `dispatch` in an unusual way, I'd encourage you to just use the object shorthand syntax that `connect` supports.  If you pass an object full of action creators as the second argument to `connect`, it will automatically run that object through `bindActionCreators` for you.  So, in this case it would be `export default connect(mapState, LayerActions)(App)`.

I do see that you're returning the results of that call as a prop named `actions`.  I started off doing that myself, but eventually switched away from it, as it required some of my components to "know" that they were connected to Redux (ie, having to call `this.props.actions.someActionCreator()` instead of `this.props.someActionCreator()`).

I wrote an article called [Idiomatic Redux: Why use action creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/) that covers some of these topics in more detail.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks so much. If I pass in my object literal of actions as the second arg, how do I then pass the injected actions injected by Connect into the Sidebar child component?

Comment: You would generally need to pull together the action-related props, and pass them down. That could be explicit (`const {firstAction} = props`), or as more of a catch-all (`const {layers, ...allOtherProps} = props`).  Either way, extract them, then render Sidebar with those props.